# Drupal 7 can't able to log in as an admin

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new to drupal. I need to make some changes to already built drupal project. i've imported mysql file and the project is running. But to make changes to the site, I need to log in as an admin. I changed password and all in users table by referring some online suggestions. but nothing is working. I'm stuck here. How can I login as admin in my drupal7 project?

Answer (score 0):

For best maintenance, install drush (Drupal Shell) and then you can call `drush uli` from the command line to receive a one-time login link.

Alternatively, make sure the admin account is connected to a valid email address you can access and then visit `https://[yourdomain]/user/password` to request a new password for the admin user account.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually my mistake was, I was supposed to give user permission. I'm new to drupal, Is it better to start from scratch or using a theme for designing a website?

Comment: Depends on the website, available budget and time, ...
If you are the only working on this project, go with a theme first and try to connect the dots (which file is doing what, learn the hooks, and so on). Once you are somewhat familiar with the theming system you can go for a custom theme built from scratch.